# Azure key vault: TLS 1.0 is no longer accepted by KeyVault Service

Tags: azure, tls1.2, azure-keyvault, azure-webapps

Azure web app cannot access Key Vault because of: The caller is using an older TLS version for authentication to Key Vault.TLS 1.0 is no longer accepted by KeyVault Service.

- Configured web app to use TLS 1.2 for inbound.
- Check web app using target framework .Net 4.7.1
- Check using latest Azure KeyVault packages

Answer (score 2):

Issue was fixed.

For my **local run** I enabled Tls 1.2 by default using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/reference-connect-tls-enforcement#powershell-script-to-enable-tls-12

For **web app** issue was in httpRuntime in web.config. Should be at least 4.6.1

```html
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.1"/>
  <httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="5000"/>
</system.web>
```